# Signed Message Verification failing for signed messages with multiple passes

Tags: web3js, etherscan, signature

I'm using web3 to verify signed messages using the code below:

```js
web3.eth.accounts.recover(message, signature);
```

I'm testing against the list of publicly verified signatures on EtherScan - https://etherscan.io/verifiedSignatures and this actually works for the vast majority of the signatures on there.

For example, by taking [this publicly verified signature](https://etherscan.io/verifySig/1406) as an example I can see that the console output is `0x65f4667a96bbfd393f39b35b84145f2521bb359c` which is as expected and verified by EtherScan

```js
web3.eth.accounts.recover("test message", "0x290aa619d5e054c3de8b5f48e2a88e0ce410b2aea2ad3deb5c2ea7e270a10f3d27c85801ad48445a37fc27eecc86bbec92748af5fde22159a8bbe923278ec43a1b")
```

However, trying to do the same with [this publicly verified signature](https://etherscan.io/verifySig/1398) returns an output of `0x31e7d77287169f0AF8aE63d276441f905A68b7aD` as a result, which does not match the address published on etherscan (`0x8F5d3Ad9A330009C751D76cAc7D27F929AC059CE`)

```js
web3.eth.accounts.recover("I have the private key for 0x8f5d3ad9a330009c751d76cac7d27f929ac059ce", "0xa45a8a4d35158f3610a7a8263c048b171fbf6ed9fe31a958e56be73323bf585d67a689dc361226512b04be308ccbe4e93b6c49c2253d2299dd243edd563299e701")
```

The exception seems to be those entries where EtherScan indicates in the results that there are multiple passes.

What does having 2 or even 3 passes to verify a signature mean, and what is the reason for doing so? I wasn't able to find documentation that goes into this

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, was finally able to figure this out. I noticed that EtherScan are thanking Nethereum for the module which I happened to be familiar with so I had a look at the `MessageSignerTests` in `Nethereum.Signer.UnitTests` and it appears that the differences lie in a mix of whether it is the raw message that's being passed to the recover function, or a hashed version of it. In addition to this we need to consider whether the Geth Prefix (`\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n<length of message>`) is being applied once or twice.

This is what I was able to deduce:

#### Verified with Pass(1)

This is the "simplest" form where the message is expected to be the text as a string (together with the Geth Prefix)

```js
web3.eth.accounts.recover(message, signature);
```

#### Verified with Pass(2)

This means that the signature's message was hashed and subsequently signed **without** the Geth Prefix, so in order to recover the address we also need to set the `preFixed` parameter to `true`, as otherwise the `web3.eth.accounts.recover` would append the Geth Prefix and validation would fail.

```js
let hashedMessage = web3.utils.keccak256(message);
web3.eth.accounts.recover(hashedMessage, signature, true);
```

#### Verified with Pass(3)

This means that the message was hashed and signed, but unlike the previous example it is **with** the Geth Prefix, so to recover we need to

```js
let hashedMessage = web3.utils.keccak256(message);
web3.eth.accounts.recover(hashedMessage, signature);
```